# Selenium Web Driver trying to find item in dropdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to Automate in Selenium Web Driver using C# and im running in to an issue where im trying to select an item in a dropdown box. But this is not a normal dropdown and i cannot seem to select a specfic item from the list. I can get the dropdown to open but when i try to send text to the search field it says "element not visible". i have also tried finding the item in the drop down but still cannot get it to find the option. Below is my Code and the HTML for the dropdown.

Any Help is much appreciated

```
var ChooseAsset = driver.FindElementById("uiAssetIdDdl_chosen");
            ChooseAsset.Click();
            var SelectAsset = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-241]')]"));
            SelectAsset.Click();
```

```html
<ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result highlighted" data-option-array-index="1" style="">CFM International LEAP-1A26 [SN: ABC123]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-139]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-152]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-241]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-258]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-307]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="7" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-309]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-369]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="9" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-38]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="10" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-458]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="11" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-502]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="12" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-608]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="13" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-62]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="14" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-655]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="15" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-664]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="16" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-694]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="17" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-749]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="18" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-816]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="19" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-875]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="20" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-888]</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="21" style="">Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-892]</li></ul>
```

Comment: Can you please share the URL

Comment: Your xpaths return multiple element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try below xpath

```
*//li[@class='active-result'][contains(text(),'Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-888')]*
```

or if it doesn't work you can anchor it via ul

```
var SelectAssets = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@class="chosen-results"]/li[]"));

for(int i=0;i<SelectAssets.length;i++){
if(SelectAssets[i].getText()="Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-888")
SelectAssets[i].click();
break;
}
```

Comment: I am not that great with C#, so not sure about the syntax although it's a simple for loop

Comment: Good answer @ Aarya Hareendranath. Please check my xpath too. it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpaths

1. Select Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-892]

   ```
   //li[@class='active-result'][contains(text(),'Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-888')]
   ```
2. Select Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-875]

   ```
   //li[@class='active-result'][contains(text(),'Airbus A300-603 [SN: AR-PL-875')]
   ```

Comment: Are u check xpaths??